# Elasticsearch analyzer for parsing the application logs

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

1. I am using the file beat and able to successfully push the logs to the elasticsearch in a particular index.
2. I have a use case where I need to find the duplicates in the logs, I tried using aggregation and I am able to find the duplicates in the logs for the exact log match like below,

   2019-07-23 11:38:17,401 WARN  [org.amazon.events] (default task-3) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=amazon, clientId=angular-cors, userId=209fd7db-6964-41ff-bffd-3975ccbc03bb, ipAddress=44.44.44.44, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, grant_type=password, client_auth_method=client-secret, username=testuser@amazon.com

   2019-07-23 11:38:17,401 WARN  [org.amazon.events] (default task-3) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=amazon, clientId=angular-cors, userId=209fd7db-6964-41ff-bffd-3975ccbc03bb, ipAddress=44.44.44.44, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, grant_type=password, client_auth_method=client-secret, username=testuser@amazon.com
3. But say the time and task id is changed like below, but still, I want to consider this as duplicate log as above

   2019-07-23 11:38:18,401 WARN  [org.amazon.events] (default task-4) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=amazon, clientId=angular-cors, userId=209fd7db-6964-41ff-bffd-3975ccbc03bb, ipAddress=44.44.44.44, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, grant_type=password, client_auth_method=client-secret, username=testuser@amazon.com

I have one way,

**Solution** :
i) If I use the standard analyzer with stopwords, I will be able to separate as tokens
ii) Skip the  and GET only the  in the tokens
iii) then use the multi-match / most-like-this query to check any logs already exist.

This is working as of now.
But Is there a better way to get only the "keywords" from the logs using analyzer, so that I won't end up with a large sets of keywords.

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: it would be great if you can also tell what all fields you want to consider as a keyword and some samples on that

Comment: I have the 'log' index which has 3 fields - hostname, logdata, title. Where the 'logdata' has the log message as posted. I want to analyze the logs, Is there a better way to find the duplicates in the logs where I want to exclude the time, uniqueId etc., and compare only the important texts @OpsterElasticsearchNinja

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja, If you need any other details let me know please

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja, Could you please check whether my request is possible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63007991/elastic-search-tokenization-and-multi-match-query

Comment: sorry for delay, just answered it on your quetion.